# Generated texture coordinates in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, texture-coordinates

How to get Generated coordinates for geometry nodes, Using the position node you can get the Object coordinates and Using a Input attribute you can get the UV Map. So I don't know how to Get the generated coordinates for Geo nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found a solution after so many trials, It so simple, just add a normalize Vector math node to the position node.